# How can I view .HEIC photos on Linux?

Tags: linux, photos, ios, h.265

How can I view .HEIC photos (the new default format on iOS 11) on a Linux desktop, without uploading them to some cloud service?  Is there an image viewer, image converter, or browser with support for .HEIC, either released or not-yet-released?

Comment: Another discussion is at https://askubuntu.com/questions/958355/any-app-on-ubuntu-to-open-heif-heic-high-efficiency-image-file-format-pictur

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For local conversion, this worked for me in Debian. Just downloaded the static build, ran the example conversion command, everything worked:

https://github.com/monostream/tifig

Comment: Yes, 0.2.0 runs on Ubuntu 18.  https://github.com/monostream/tifig/releases/download/0.2.0/tifig-static-0.2.0.tar.gz

Comment: v0.2.2 works great as a static download on Ubuntu 20.04 as wel

Comment: At the time of writing, this no longer works with photos from newer iOS versions. You will get the error message: "Grid configuration not found! tifig currently only supports .heic images created on iOS 11 devices."

Answer (score 51):

On Ubuntu (Debian distro) the easiest way is probably to run:

```
sudo apt install heif-gdk-pixbuf
```

For Fedora and other RPM-based distros use:

```
sudo dnf install libheif
```

After this, e.g. Eye of Gnome `eog image.heic` will display your image.

Comment: This is the better and less setup required. After installed "heif-gdk-pixbuf" you can open the heic files directly, if not, just right click the heic file and "Open in Another Application" --> Image Viewer

Comment: Yeah this is newer but now clearly the correct answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 20. I just get a white panel.

Comment: After this Fedoras bundled "Image Viewer" could pull them up for me - thanks!

Comment: Didn't work in Mint 19; after installing Image Viewer and GIMP could still not open them. And the ffmpeg command didn't work either. Installing `libheif-examples` in the other answer and using `heif-convert` does work.

Comment: Ristretto (XFCE) also opened a HEIF image for me when installed `libheif` on Fedora. Note that the package is from RPM Fusion. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work with with Eye of Mate on 22.04

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: I'm getting *"E: Unable to locate package heif-gdk-pixbuf"* error on my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Would greatly appreciate any help/tips to resolve this error. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: On Fedora 38 I had to install heif-pixbuf-loader as well

Comment: Doesn't work Debian 12.

Answer (score 26):

to convert a heic image to be able to view it as usual,

```
sudo apt-get install libheif-examples
```

then convert image to jpg:

```
heif-convert input.heic output.jpg
```

then view the image using any image viewer - here's an example:

```
ristretto  output.jpg
```

Comment: The heif-convert step worked.  Not sure what 'ristretto' is?

Comment: @Ellipticalview [Ristretto Image Viewer](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/ristretto/start)

Comment: Any image viewer wold work: mentioning a specific one as part of the solution workflow the way you did is out of the scope of the question, so it looks like an advertisement...

Comment: @FrancescoPotortì the answer is now updated to explicitly state that any image viewer would work; I used ristretto as an example because it was already installed

Comment: For all files in directory: `for i in *.HEIC; do heif-convert "$i" "$i.jpg"; done`

Comment: Like @fracz but without the "file.HEIC.jpg" double extension: `for i in *.HEIC; do heif-convert "$i" "${i%.HEIC}.jpg"; done`

Comment: for those on rpm-based systems such as Fedora: the package providing `heif-convert` is `libheif-tools`.

Answer (score 8):

For the record, ImageMagick supports it. Somehow `magick display image.heic` gave me weird results, but converting was fine:

```
magick convert image.heic image.jpg
```

Comment: On Debian 10.3 I have to use `convert-im6.q16` rather than `magick`.  (From 'imagemagick' package v 8:6.9.10.23+..). 

 (Also GIMP opens them, but it's more awkward and much more slow.) 

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`.heic` may be the file name extension, but the format is more commonly known as HEIF, the High Efficiency Image File format. There’s an open source implementation from Nokia here: http://nokiatech.github.io/heif/

Answer (score 4):

You could convert it to a supported format using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i image.heic image.png
```

Comment: Apparently ffmpeg [does not yet support HEIF](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6521)?

Comment: Just took a photo on an iPhone and ran the .heic file through ffmpeg with the above command. Converted to png without any problems. Not sure why the people in that post are having issues.

Comment: Not working for me.  I'm seeing:

$ ffmpeg -i IMG_9256.heic IMG_9256.png
ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdi

Comment: o --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq

Comment: --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100

Comment: [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55a711614740] moov atom not found
IMG_9256.heic: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: I am also getting "moov atom not found" with FFmpeg 4.4.2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove previous version of ImageMagick:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove imagemagick
   ```
2. Install base dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall 
   sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxext-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev
   sudo apt-get install libwebp-dev libde265-dev
   ```
3. Install library for reading **HEIF/HEIC** files (this step is essential):

   ```
   cd /usr/src/
   sudo wget https://github.com/strukturag/libheif/archive/v1.3.2.tar.gz
   sudo tar -xvf v1.3.2.tar.gz
   sudo rm v1.3.2.tar.gz
   cd libheif-1.3.2/
   sudo ./autogen.sh
   sudo ./configure
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   ```
4. Install ImageMagick with WEBP and HEIC support:

   ```
   cd /usr/src/
   sudo wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
   sudo tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
   sudo rm ImageMagick.tar.gz
   cd ImageMagick-7.0.10-31/
   sudo ./configure --with-heic=yes --with-webp=yes
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
   sudo make check
   ```
5. Check version:

   ```
   convert --version
   ...
   Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-31 Q16 x86_64 2020-10-03 https://imagemagick.org
   Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
   License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
   Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.0) 
   Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jpeg lcms lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
   ```
6. As you see *'heic'* is in the delegates list.
7. To convert single file from HEIC into JPG:

   ```
   convert IMG_3288.HEIC IMG_3288.jpg
   ```
8. To convert all HEIC-files in current directory into JPEG:

   ```
   ls *.HEIC -1 | sed -e 's/\.HEIC$//' | xargs -I {} convert {}.HEIC {}.jpeg
   ```

---

Usefull links:

https://medium.com/@sanjaywrites/install-latest-version-of-imagemagick-in-ubuntu-16-04-c406ddea1973
https://gist.github.com/rjnienaber/af47fccb8410926ba7ea35f96c3b87fd

Comment: `for img in *{heic,HEIC}; do convert "${img}"{,.jpg}; done` (Not sure how portable it is though, and it does just append the JPEG extension at the end - although I like converting like that as it gives a sense of "format history".)

Comment: I woud refrain from installing archives from an unknown GitHub repo - can contain anything.

Comment: Both HEIC and JPEG formats are lossy, which means quality losses, when converting from HEIC to JPEG, hence, I don't think, that this approach is right overall!

Comment: `sudo snap install regardsviewer` works for me, unfortunately, I can't write the answer due to not enough reputation rate.

Answer (score 2):

GIMP 2.10.8 installs the library libheif1 to open HEIC images, other linux programs can be expected to follow soon.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case any [openSUSE](https://www.opensuse.org/) user finds this.

Add the [Packman](https://en.opensuse.org/Additional_package_repositories#Packman) repo and then:

```
# zypper in libheif1 gdk-pixbuf-loader-libheif gimp-plugin-heif
```

After that, I was able to open .HEIC photos using [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a little old but since these posts I've found a Gimp plugin and even a QT plugin for KDE support. Hope these help someone in the future.

```
sudo dnf install gimp-heif-plugin qt-heif-image-plugin
```

Comment: `sudo snap install regardsviewer` supports HEIC. IMHO, it's better to find one dedicated image viewer for this naughty image format, than try to install plugins, as in my case such packages are not even present!

Answer (score 1):

Debian:

```
apt install viewnior heif-gdk-pixbuf
viewnior file.heic
```

or

```
apt install gpicview heif-gdk-pixbuf
gpicview file.heic
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Fedora 33 and I'm unable to edit a `.HEIC` image using neither `convert` (ImageMagick 6.9.11.27), `ffmpeg` 4.3.3, GIMP 2.10.24, nor Inkscape 1.0.2.

The only app that does the job for me is Shutter 0.99.1.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you need libheif in fc33. *dnf install libheif* and eog

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).